# how to specify an activity to run once in onCreate

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

i'd like my activity after installation to run the onCreate method once. Meaning if i come out of the app and return the onresume runs instead of oncreate. I know you can set a FLAGS_ACTIVITY... with intents, but i'd like to set it in the manifest.

thanks Matt

Comment: If the activity was destroyed by Android while you were "out of the app", there is no way to bypass `onCreate()`.

Comment: What about `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your manifest under `<activity>`. Though there is no way to bypass onCreate() if Android destroyed your app, just as others have stated.

Comment: @Geobits The problem is that the caches a website on the sdcard. I've done this by using a Intentservice attached to an Alarm manager. It doesn't matter if i put it in onresume or oncreate it runs when i re-enter the app. I want it to run on the first run then on subsequent runs it doesn't. the alarmManager will run the code at a given inteval. As it stands i'm creating a new alarm each time i re-enter the app

Comment: @turtleboy You should try calling from the onCreate() method another method that verifies if an Alarm is already set. If not, then create it, else do nothing.

Comment: @CristianEduardoLehuedeLyon hi yes i did that. i set i flag to ensure it only runs once but what is happening is android is creating a new instance of the app. I think TronicZomB has sorted it thanks

Comment: @TronicZomB thanks i think that worked. make an answer and i'll accept. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `android:launchMode="singleTask"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bypass the method onCreate() if the application has been closed by the android OS or the user killing it. Maybe you should rethink the way your program is being written to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, you can't bypass `onCreate()` if your activity is killed.

To address your issue, you should probably move the caching code out of `onCreate()` altogether. `onResume()` is a better place for it. However, that won't solve your problem unless you figure out some way to check if the action has already taken place.